# How to calculate all pairwise abs differences among many variables in R

Tags: r, vector, pairwise

I need to calculate all pairwise abs differences among many variables (there are 100 in my dataset).
I expect to get one column for each difference:

I have tried the next function but it summarizes the results, and I do not need the sum, but all the single abs differences.

```
outer(seq_along(rio_csv), seq_along(rio_csv), FUN =
              Vectorize(function(i, j)abs(sum(rio_csv[[i]] - rio_csv[[j]], na.rm = FALSE))))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(v1=1:6,V2=7:12,V3=13:18,v4=19:24,v5=25:30,v6=31:36)
```

Comment: What do you want as an output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What probably irritated you is that `outer` did not work when you delete the `sum` (I'm sure you tried that). That's because the `Vectorize` result can not be simplified into a matrix (the default), so we may set it to `FALSE`

```
r <- outer(seq_along(df), seq_along(df),
           FUN=Vectorize(function(i, j) abs(df[[i]] - df[[j]]), SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

### Result

```
matrix(unlist(r), nrow(df))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36]
# [1,]    0    6   12   18   24   30    6    0    6    12    18    24    12     6     0     6    12    18    18    12     6     0     6    12    24    18    12     6     0     6    30    24    18    12     6     0
# [2,]    0    6   12   18   24   30    6    0    6    12    18    24    12     6     0     6    12    18    18    12     6     0     6    12    24    18    12     6     0     6    30    24    18    12     6     0
# [3,]    0    6   12   18   24   30    6    0    6    12    18    24    12     6     0     6    12    18    18    12     6     0     6    12    24    18    12     6     0     6    30    24    18    12     6     0
# [4,]    0    6   12   18   24   30    6    0    6    12    18    24    12     6     0     6    12    18    18    12     6     0     6    12    24    18    12     6     0     6    30    24    18    12     6     0
# [5,]    0    6   12   18   24   30    6    0    6    12    18    24    12     6     0     6    12    18    18    12     6     0     6    12    24    18    12     6     0     6    30    24    18    12     6     0
# [6,]    0    6   12   18   24   30    6    0    6    12    18    24    12     6     0     6    12    18    18    12     6     0     6    12    24    18    12     6     0     6    30    24    18    12     6     0
```

Comment: Indeed I did try to remove the **sum**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `combn` will give you want you want. By itself, it just reports the combinations, but you can provide a function that is passed a single argument, a vector length-2 of the two indicates.

```r
combn(6,2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2     3     3     3     4     4     5
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    3    4    5    6     4     5     6     5     6     6
combn(6, 2, FUN = function(i) df[,i[1]] - df[,i[2]])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# [1,]   -6  -12  -18  -24  -30   -6  -12  -18  -24    -6   -12   -18    -6   -12    -6
# [2,]   -6  -12  -18  -24  -30   -6  -12  -18  -24    -6   -12   -18    -6   -12    -6
# [3,]   -6  -12  -18  -24  -30   -6  -12  -18  -24    -6   -12   -18    -6   -12    -6
# [4,]   -6  -12  -18  -24  -30   -6  -12  -18  -24    -6   -12   -18    -6   -12    -6
# [5,]   -6  -12  -18  -24  -30   -6  -12  -18  -24    -6   -12   -18    -6   -12    -6
# [6,]   -6  -12  -18  -24  -30   -6  -12  -18  -24    -6   -12   -18    -6   -12    -6
```

For instance, the first time the anon-func is called, `i` is `c(1L, 2L)`.